# Domain Accounts for SQL Server Database Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, active-directory, database-project

I have an SQL Server Database Project which I've filled via importing from a database on a client's domain. I've been given access to this database via domain accounts. The permissions setup for this database are all domain accounts.

For testing, I am able to publish to a local SQL Express server included with Visual Studio. When I publish to a local server for testing on a dev machine in the domain, the domain accounts work fine.

The question then is, when I want to test on a machine that is not on their domain, how can I leave in the domain configuration? Is there a way to fake the domain in the local instance? Currently the scripts point to WINDOWS for these accounts.

EDIT: I've tried using AD LDS and it seems that SQL can't authenticate against it? Maybe I've not integrated it into WINDOWS properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this isn't something that's easily done within SSDT. The best way I've found to do this is to use roles to handle the security, role memberships to grant permissions, and environment variables combined with post-deploy scripts to handle permissions.  I borrowed the idea from Jamie Thomson and blogged about it here: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/05/ssdt-setting-different-permissions-per.html

This would let you set permissions to test locally, but still publish the DB elsewhere and set permissions appropriately in each environment. Just remember to set up your logins/users to check for existence before creating them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried your script and it seems to have worked pretty well! I've run into an issue though. The developer machines aren't domain-connected, so I can't do something like have each dev create the three groups we'll be using (DBO, W, R) on their local machine then just refer to the group by name (for creating users/logins). Do you know of any way to grab either the current domain or current user when creating a new user? If so, this would be the complete answer for me.

Comment: Fixed the issue with Dynamic SQL.

Comment: For local machines, I usually left the permissions alone or used something like SUSER_SNAME(). :)  Sounds like you found the solution for your environment, though.

Comment: We need to check different permissions levels though, so we have multiple local groups and can run our services as a user of the group for testing. I didn't want to just gloss over that in case it causes some issues in production or QA that could have been caught in dev.

Comment: Any chance you're using DB roles? That can make that quite a bit easier to test. Change someone in and out of various roles. Use SETUSER or similar to change the context. If all security is assigned to DB roles and then users/groups are added to those, you can control the security a bit better. I definitely recommend that over assigning permissions directly to the users/groups.